# How do I import my music and photos to Ubuntu installed on VMWare Virtual Machine?

Tags: vmware

I have installed Ubuntu in VMWare, and I want to import all my movies, music and photos, to VMWare Ubuntu. How do you guys suggest I should do this?

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu inside VMWare?? What is the host OS then & where are the files located which you would like import/copy?

Comment: windows 7 ultimate x64

Answer (score 1):

#### Using shared directories/folders between Ubuntu guest and Windows host:

Here are the steps how you can get this done:

1. Start the *VMware* virtualization software *(but don't boot the Ubuntu VM yet)*,
2. Select your Ubuntu VM and click to open the settings,
   [image: snap1]
3. From the settings window, select *Options* tab and click on *Shared Folders* to enable and click <kbd>Add...</kbd> button to add one or more directories to the list of shared folders,
4. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> to save the settings and start your Ubuntu VM,
5. In Ubuntu VM, shared folders should appear under `/mnt/hgfs`, but if you don't find it there continue to step 6,
6. Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and enter the following commands

   ```
    sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
   ```
7. To check to see if Ubuntu is aware that there is a shared folder available run this command in a terminal window:

   ```
    vmware-hgfsclient
   ```
8. To run the VMWare config tools:

   ```
    vmware-config-tools.pl
   ```

---

Sources:

- [VMware Workstation 4.5](https://www.vmware.com/support/ws45/doc/running_sharefold_ws.html)
- [How to share folders between Windows and Ubuntu using VMware Player](http://theholmesoffice.com/how-to-share-folders-between-windows-and-ubuntu-using-vmware-player/)